# I could be bigger, but I'm still small -- What am I?

Tags: riddle

> We all look alike, but never the exact same
>
> We need more of 'us' to be pretty
>
> I've been invented at least 50 years ago.

What am I?

Hints will follow

---

> Even though there could be thousands, even millions.. If I die, you'll notice.

Comment: Minions? Just joking.

Comment: If you think hints are necessary to solve the riddle, then include them in the original puzzle. The goal of a riddle creator should be to create a puzzle which can be solved without hints.

Comment: @MorganG The hints I'm thinking off would instantly spoil the riddle. You wouldn't need hints to answer this,but it would help tremendously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a :

> pixel !

We all look alike, but never the exact same

> Every pixels are the same, but they also have [differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Bits_per_pixel).

We need more of 'us' to be pretty

> Full HD for the win! Hum, well, the more pixels you have, the more beautiful the image is.

I've been invented at least 50 years ago.

> Well, I guess you're refering to its [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Etymology).

The hint :

> You ALWAYS notice a dead pixel. Always.

Comment: This is what I thought of, too.

Comment: @IanMacDonald What do you mean?

Comment: Just that I provided your answer 10 minutes before you posted it.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oh, I did not even see your comment on the other answer! It is the hint that gave me the answer. Nice catch anyway, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

One possible answer is

> A 1-inch decorative tile

We all look alike, but never the exact same

> They're all similar

We need more of 'us' to be pretty

> Arrange many tiles together and you can create pretty murals

I've been invented at least 50 years ago.

> Tiles have been in use for way more than 50 years

Comment: That's a good answer but I think the key word is 'possible'. This question seems too broad to me

Comment: I don't disagree.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You are incredibly close.

Comment: Perhaps you want "pixels in an LCD".

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> an LED

We all look alike, but never the exact same

> the brightness and color makes them all slightly different

We need more of 'us' to be pretty

> You need a lot of them to create an image

I've been invented at least 50 years ago

> LED's were invented more than 50 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's

> Cash/Dollar Bills

We all look alike, but never the exact same

> Bills look very similar, but have different serial numbers

We need more of 'us' to be pretty

> Large amounts of money is something most people want, small amounts less so

I've been invented at least 50 years ago.

> The current 1$ bill uses the design from 1963, bills in general are far older.

Hint:

> People tend to notice when they accidentally destroy money, additionally, if the 1$ bill dies off in general (maybe replaced by a coin, or just digitized away) it would be very obvious.

Title:

> 'I could be bigger, but I'm still small' instantly made me think of my bank account. Deciding whether that says something about me personally, or is another clue is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> A Brick

We all look alike, but never the exact same

> Bricks all look similar but each is unique in exact appearance

We need more of 'us' to be pretty

> You need a lot of them to make a nice looking wall or street

I've been invented at least 50 years ago

> They have been in use well over 50 years

Hint:

> Some mansions can take millions of bricks to construct, if one is broken it stands out.